# How to add multiple servlets (Google Endpoint) to web.xml in android studio?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio

I added another endpoint to my android studio google endpoint but I can't make it work. Does somebody know how to make it work?
Here is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.mymodule.TestEndpoint.MyEndpoint</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestServeletas</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.mymodule.TestEndpoint.OuniKiousEndpoint</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.mymodule.TestEndpoint.OuniKiousEndpoint</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestServeletas</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/oki/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Weirdly, the solution of @iniro doesn't work for me, even though it's what's document on the [gradle plugin's page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin#convention-properties).

What works for me is simply [editing the web.xml for multi class APIs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/required_files?hl=fr#webxml), using comma-separated endpoints:

```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.mybackend.MyEndpoint1, com.mybackend.MyEndpoint2</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
//End of the web.xml file
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution.
Don`t use web.xml, use this entry in the build.gradle file

```
endpoints {
    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    serviceClasses = [ 'com.example.app.endpoints.Endpoint1',
                       'com.example.app.endpoints.Endpoint2' ]
  }
```

I hope this helps you.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Ok. I'll try it later and let you know.

Comment: I updated Android Studio and It doesnt works!
Thanks to MagicMicky, now I deployed my 2 endpoints but now I have this error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.example.app.endpoints.EMF

Comment: I fixed it migrating to objectify